# How to set the layer texture2d image in unity

Tags: unity, c#, gui

I am working on onscreen arrow indicator. I have placed some sphere on the screen and attached the code below to each gameobject. And also I have a canvas,which consist of a panel.

```
public Texture2D icon; //The icon. Preferably an arrow pointing upwards.
public float iconSize = 50f;
[HideInInspector]
public GUIStyle arrowIndicator; //GUIStyle to make the box around the icon invisible. Public so that everything has the default stats.
Vector2 indRange;
float scaleRes = Screen.width / 500; //The width of the screen divided by 500. Will make the GUI automatically
//scale with varying resolutions.
Camera cam;
public bool visible = false; //Whether or not the object is visible in the camera.

void Start () {
    visible = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().isVisible;

    cam = Camera.main; //Don't use Camera.main in a looping method, its very slow, as Camera.main actually
    //does a GameObject.Find for an object tagged with MainCamera.

    indRange.x = Screen.width - (Screen.width / 6);
    indRange.y = Screen.height - (Screen.height / 7);
    indRange /= 2f;

    arrowIndicator.normal.textColor = new Vector4 (0, 0, 0, 0); //Makes the box around the icon invisible.

}

void OnGUI () {
    if (visible) {
        Vector3 dir = transform.position - cam.transform.position;
        dir = Vector3.Normalize (dir);
        dir.y *= -1f;

        Vector2 indPos = new Vector2 (indRange.x * dir.x, indRange.y * dir.y);
        indPos = new Vector2 ((Screen.width / 2) + indPos.x,
            (Screen.height / 2) + indPos.y);

        Vector3 pdir = transform.position - cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(indPos.x, indPos.y,
            transform.position.z));
        pdir = Vector3.Normalize(pdir);

        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(pdir.x, pdir.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        GUIUtility.RotateAroundPivot(angle, indPos); //Rotates the GUI. Only rotates GUI drawn after the rotate is called, not before.
        GUI.Box (new Rect (indPos.x, indPos.y, scaleRes * iconSize, scaleRes * iconSize), icon,arrowIndicator);
        GUIUtility.RotateAroundPivot(0, indPos); //Rotates GUI back to the default so that GUI drawn after is not rotated.
    }
}

public void OnBecameInvisible() {
    visible = false;
}
//Turns off the indicator if object is onscreen.
public void OnBecameVisible() {
    visible = true;
}
```

the onscreen arrow is getting displayed on the screen

[image]

the problem is that ,the arrow mark is getting displayed on the canvas. I need to  display the arrow mark below the canvas.Is there any way to set the layer,so that the arrow is visible below the canvas.

Comment: Set the sort order of the arrow and the canvas.  The sort order will determine in what order they will be drawn to screen.

Comment: I have set the order.Still its not working